# add custom html source code button in p-editor of primeng

Tags: angular, angular5, primeng, text-editor, quill

please give a brief idea with example of how to add a custom html source code edit button in p-editor of primeng!
As, it is not provided in default p-editor format.
Please help me in this context.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Don't know how to do it on p-editor, but this might give you an idea on how to do it. https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/128#issuecomment-306007774

Answer (score 1):

If you load the content in "ngOnInit" or in the constructor, the editor won't fail.  However if you want to load dynamically, I think that you must use a different var and then replace it

**OR**

Use this function before assign that var

```
escapeHtml(text) {
    if (!text) {
      text = '';
    }
    text += '';
    text = text
      .replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
      .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
      .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
      .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
      .replace(/&#039;/g, '\'');
    return text;
  }
```